# Strange property of Expo.Pedometer.getStepCountAsync

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I’m not sure if it’s problem with Expo or iOS pedometer, but I noticed strange behavior described below.

Imagine we have time interval `t1` - `t2` separated by `t0`, i.e. `t1 < t0 < t2`. Now if we take step count in each of these intervals:

```js
import { Pedometer } from 'expo';

const steps1 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t1, t0);
const steps2 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t2);
const steps3 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t1, t2);
```

I would expect the following difference to be close to 0 (if not 0 all the time):

```js
difference = steps1 + steps2 - steps3
```

But I noticed, that in practice, this is often not true. The difference might be `100`, `200` or even `1000` steps. What’s worse, if you try to “move” `t0` in the example, this difference also changes.

What's worse, it doesn't seem to be happening always. My iPhone 8, has this problem, maybe 2 days in a month. And despite the fact it looks quite foolish, but I noticed it happens when there are some connectivity problems during the day.

Question: Why are not steps in each interval equal to the steps in the union interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution for this.

When you want to find steps in the interval from t1 to t2, instead of:

```js
const steps = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t1, t2);
```

do the following:

```js
const t0 = new Date(0);
const steps1 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t1);
const steps2 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t2);
const steps = steps2 - steps1; // THIS IS THE ANSWER!
```

That doesn't solve the issue with Pedometer/Expo itself, but gives stable solution: all steps in subintervals now add up to steps in the whole interval.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

Solution above worked for iOS, but it crashes Pedometer on Android. So I came with another solution (to use shorter interval):

```js
const t0 = startOfDay(t1); // beginning of the same day works fine for me
const steps1 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t1);
const steps2 = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t2);
const steps = steps2 - steps1; // THIS IS THE ANSWER!
```

**ONE MORE IMPORTANT UPDATE**

Also I noticed that if you do something like:

```
await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(t0, t0); // when both parameters are equal
```

This also crashes on Android.

**EVEN MORE IMPORTANT UPDATE**

Please note, that `t0` should be beginning of the day!!! I learned about it while experimenting with different devices. Also to avoid Android bug when same the times are passed, just add a wrapper function which checks dates equality and returns `0` in such case.